# How do you call a metric space with "continuous" points?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

I have the impression that "continuous space" is not a mathematically precise concept (as opposed to continuous functions that can be defined under various contexts).  However, I find I need to refer to a vague notion of continuous spaces very often in my research.

How does one call a metric space X where for every 2 points x, y, one can always find a third point whose distance is intermediate between x and y?

In other words:
$$ \forall x \neq y \in X.  \exists z \in X. d(x,z) < d(x,y) \wedge d(y,z) < d(x,y)$$

This might be called a "continuous" space if there is no such definition before?

==== Edit ====

I also found the defintion of "complete" metric spaces where every Cauchy sequence converges to a point within that space.  However, a complete space seems to require "irrational" points as well as rational points, whereas my requirement can be met by rational points only.  So my requirement might be weaker than a complete metric space.

Comment: Yes, changed accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you described doesn't quite hit "continuum" since $\mathbb{Q}$ has that property. However, spaces which are "locally Euclidean", ie neighborhoods in this space look like neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}^n$, along with a few other properties is called a manifold.

Comment: Yes, I also found the description of "complete" metric spaces where every Cauchy sequence converges to a point in the space.  This requires the space to contain "irrational" points as well as rational points, whereas my requirement seems to be met by a space with rational points only.

Comment: Well $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countable metric space without isolate points. Is that more what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not just looking for examples, I'm looking for a definition of such spaces, and to see if any example other than $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is in it.

Comment: Well I think the lack of isolated points is the key to what you're looking for.

Comment: It seems that the smallest space with such a property is $\mathbb{Q}^n$.

Comment: Any connected subset of that would have the same property.

Comment: I mean you can always equip a set with the discrete metric, and you will always get a complete metric space, so I don't think its "weaker". I agree with Joe that a space without isolated points(the discrete part) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @YanKingYin You can't have a non-empty finite space with more than one point with the property you want, so any example will be at least countably infinite. You can adjoin things to $\mathbb Q$, for example $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ will have this property. So there are lots of examples.

Comment: I think the notion of Hausdorff space may be relevant here...  my requirement implies Hausdorff, so Hausdorff may be a more general notion of "continuous space".

Comment: Well completely disconnected spaces are Hausdorff.